# Выделить из абзаца HTML картинку и текст

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, синтаксический-анализ

Допустим, у нас есть такой кусок:

```
<p><a href="http://site.com"><img src="image.jpg" rel="bla" title="bla" /></a>A purus, velit proin ut magnis habitasse et! Sociis etiam a ac, augue mattis, porttitor? Adipiscing aenean vel natoque amet ultricies placerat scelerisque augue, dignissim adipiscing turpis! Adipiscing, nascetur risus velit sed tortor magnis penatibus. A tempor aliquet dolor. Amet proin non placerat non pulvinar enim elementum urna? Pulvinar pid enim! Non odio parturient cum et pulvinar mid porta in natoque augue?</p>
```

Причем, картинка может быть, а может и не быть. А если она есть то может быть как со ссылкой, так и без нее...

Задача: если есть картинки в тексте, выбрать первую картинку юез ссылки в одну переменную, а остаток текста (проигнорировав остальные картинки) - в другую переменную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = '<p><img src="image.jpg" rel="bla" title="bla" />A purus, velit proin ut magnis habitasse et! Sociis etiam a ac, augue mattis, porttitor? Adipiscing aenean vel natoque amet ultricies placerat scelerisque augue, dignissim adipiscing turpis! Adipiscing, nascetur risus velit sed tortor magnis penatibus. A tempor aliquet dolor. Amet proin non placerat non pulvinar enim elementum urna? Pulvinar pid enim! Non odio parturient cum et pulvinar mid porta in natoque augue?</p>';
$img = '';
$noimg = $a;
preg_match('/(<a[^>]+>)?(<img[^>]+>)(<\/a>)?/', $a, $m);
if($m[2]){
    $img = $m[2];
    $noimg = str_replace($m[0], '', $noimg);
}
```

На выходе две переменные: $img - тег картинки, $noimg - текст без ссылки с картинкой

Comment: Все отлично, только если в тексте появляется две картинки то вторая из кода не убирается...

Answer (score 0):

Тестить регулярку не собираюсь, но вот как-то примерно так:

```
preg_match('/<img .*>/u', $siteStr, $images); // теперь в $images у нас будет хранится первое вхождение
```

Comment: @AlexWindHope, перед кодом ставится 4 пробела. Или код выделяется и жмется кнопка с 101010.

Comment: за собой смотрите, ок? вон у вс постом выше никаких пробелов нет

Comment: А я и смотрю. 4 пробела перед строкой редактор преобразует в серый блок с подсветкой кода. Простите, если написал грубовато. Это не претензия, а совет. =)

Comment: действительно грубовато получилось, я просто из разряда пока не трогай г не будет в xD